# Error `sec_error_revoked_certificate` when viewed in Firefox only

Tags: security, firefox, browser, ssl

I have an SSL certificate that does not inhibit the loading of a client's site when viewed in Chrome, Safari, or Android Browser. Unfortunately, when viewed in Firefox, I encounter the following error message:

```
An error occurred during a connection to www.rzim.org.

Peer's Certificate has been revoked.

(Error code: sec_error_revoked_certificate)
```

My only "lead" online was concerning intermediate certificates. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

The instructions provided in the answer by [Arjun KP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1862769/arjun-kp) don't work for more recent versions of Firefox (tested on v. 57.0.1). Instead, here's what I did:

1. Enter `about:config` in the address bar, accepting the risk if prompted.
2. Enter `security.OCSP.enabled` in the search bar.
3. Change the value of that setting from `1` to `0`.
4. Reload the page that failed.

After doing this, my site started working.

However, as Arjun mentioned, this will reduce the security of Firefox, since it disables the [Online Certificate Status Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol). Ideally, you should reset the setting to `1` after you finish with that site, and not load other pages while it is set to `0`.

Comment: This did not work for me. The problem is in my case that the webserver has a new valid certificate, but the OSCP server is not updated. You can check any URL here: https://certificatetools.com/ocsp-checker

Answer (score 16):

When Firefox web browser checks a security certificate, it also checks with the issuing authority if the certificate is valid. It appears that, near a certificate’s expiration date, the issuing authority may release a new certificate. The two certificates have conflicting expiration dates.

For reasons unknown, this caused Firefox to report a sec_error_revoked_certificate error and refuse to allow you to connect to the site!

You can go through the following steps, but it will reduce the security.

1. Firefox main menu -> edit ->Preferences
2. click on Advanced Tab
3. select certificates
4. click on validation
5. Uncheck the option "Use the Online Certificate status
   protocol(OCSP).........."
6. Click OK button

Now you can see the page with out error.

Answer (score 3):

An update to ARJUN KP's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24934346/9347679), which works with Firefox Quantum, v68:

- Open Firefox options
- Privacy & Security
- At the bottom, under Certificates, uncheck: "Query OCSP responder servers to confirm the current validity of certificate

Answer (score 2):

If you have this problem you can check if the cause is a negative OSCP server response. In my case the website has a new valid certificate but the OSCP server is not updated and Firefox refuses to show the page. The OSCP server still says that certificate is revoked.

Here you can check any URL:
https://certificatetools.com/ocsp-checker

[image: OSCP Check any URL]

Answer (score -1):

Haven't yet been able to find the elusive "Advanced" button though I've been to numerous forums and it is referred to often. The solution here didn't work because the "Use the online certificate protocol" doesn't exist under Preferences>Security>Certificates. QUERY OCSP responder exists and I unchecked that.